# wrong penalty was displayed when it reach its due date

Tags: php

[image]

When the due date was reached, instead of displaying the penalty as 25 it will display 0. When I moved the date after due date it will display 25.

Here's my code.

```
$Borrow_Query = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*, e.* FROM tblUser a, tblBorrowed b, tblResources c, tblCategory d, tblResourcesType e WHERE a.User_ID = '".$_GET['User_ID']."' AND b.User_ID = a.User_ID AND b.Accession_No = c.Accession_No AND c.Category_ID = d.Category_ID AND c.Type_ID = e.Type_ID ");
    while ($Show = mysql_fetch_array($Borrow_Query)){

    $DueDate = $Show['Due_Date'];

    $timezone = "Asia/Manila";
    if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')){
        date_default_timezone_set($timezone);   

        $CURTIME2 = date('h:i a');
        $CURDATE2 = date('F d,Y');
    }

    $AllowedTime_Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblAllowed_Days");
    $AllowedTime_Row = mysql_fetch_array($AllowedTime_Query);
    $Time = $AllowedTime_Row['Time'];

    $Penalty_Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblPenalty");
    $Penalty_Row = mysql_fetch_array($Penalty_Query);
    $Fine = $Penalty_Row['Penalty'];

    $Date_Time = $CURDATE2.' '.$Time;

    if($Date_Time >= $DueDate){
        $Fines = round((float)(strtotime($Date_Time) - strtotime($DueDate)) / (60 * 60 * 24) * ($Fine));
    }else{
        $Fines = 'No Penalty';  
    }
?>
```

Comment: how are `$Date_Time` and `$DueDate` presented?  are they date formats or strings?

Comment: Yep you are comparing strings, use this `if( strtotime( $Date_Time ) > strtotime( $DueDate ) )`

Comment: i will try it now sir. thanks :)

Comment: Blinkydamo - still now working sir.

Answer (score 0):

use `strtotime` funtion for date comparision in PHP.

ex, `if(strtotime($Date_Time) > strtotime($DueDate)){ ...`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this works but I am unsure what you are trying to get from `$Fines` as you are multiplying a time difference  by what I presume is an int and then rounding it?

Anyway here you go, something to play with.

```
<?php
$CURDATE2  = '2016-10-10';
$Time      = '12:12:12';
$DueDate   = '2016-09-09 12:12:12';
$Date_Time = $CURDATE2.' '.$Time;
$Fine      = 20;

if( strtotime( $Date_Time ) > strtotime( $DueDate ) )
{
  $Fines = round( (float) (strtotime( $Date_Time ) - ( strtotime( $DueDate ) ) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) * ( $Fine ) ), 2 );
}
else
{
  $Fines = 'No Penalty';  
}
echo $Fines;
```

Comment: still displaying zero sir